# Django: How to get values from my model field and use it to search for an online image, then store the image url in the model?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, web-scraping, django-templates

Using Python 3
I have a Django project with an anime app. The anime app has a model as follows:

```
class Anime(models.Model):
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    genre = CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False)
    TV = "TV/Series"
    MOVIE = "Movie"
    SPECIAL = "Special"
    OVA = "OVA"
    UNKNOWN = "Unknown"
    MUSIC = "Music"
    ONA = "ONA"
    typeChoices = (
        (TV, "TV/Series"),
        (MOVIE, "Movie"),
        (SPECIAL, "Special"),
        (OVA, "OVA"),
        (ONA, "ONA"),
        (MUSIC, "Music"),
        (UNKNOWN, "Unknown")
    )
    animeType = CharField(max_length=10, choices=typeChoices, default=TV, blank="False")
    episodes = IntegerField()
    rating = FloatField()
    members = IntegerField()

    photoCover = ImageField(null=True, upload_to="img/covers", verbose_name="cover photo", blank=True)
```

I'd like to get the name of the anime (data is inputted by a csv or a form input) and use it in a google search and get the first image of the search. I have this code that may help me do that.

```
    import urllib
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    searchName = searchName.replace(" ", "%20")
    searchName = searchName.replace("-", "%2D")
    searchName = searchName.replace("&", "%26")

    html = urllib.urlopen("http://www.google.com/search?q="+searchName+"&tbm=isch")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    img_links = soup.findAll("img", {"class":"rg_ic"})
    for img_link in img_links:
        print(img_link.img['src'])
```

What I don't know is if this would work and if it would work, I don't know where to apply the code. I'd want to use `img_link.img['src']` as the value for the `Anime.photoCover.url` as it would be in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Use this below function to save url into the image field

```
import urllib
import os
from django.core.files import File
from . models import Anime

def create_anime_from_url(name, genre, animeType, episodes, rating, members, url):
      obj = Anime.objects.create(
        name=name, genre=genre, animeType=animeType,
        episodes=episodes, rating=rating, members=members
      )
      photoCover = urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)
      obj.photoCover.save(
          os.path.basename(url),
          # File(open(photoCover[0]))
          '  '
      )
```

If you don't want to store the image url into file system then you have to use the `CustomFileSystemStorage` to handle the functionality.

```
class CustomFileSystemStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def _save(self, name, content):
        if name.startswith('https://') or name.startswith('http://'):
              return name
        return super(CustomFileSystemStorage, self)._save(name, content)
    def url(self, name):
        if name.startswith('https://') or name.startswith('http://'):
              return name
        return super(CustomFileSystemStorage, self).url(name)

class Anime(models.Model):
# .............
    photoCover = ImageField(
       null=True, upload_to="img/covers",
       verbose_name="cover photo", blank=True,
       storage=CustomFileSystemStorage())
# .............
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `module 'urllib' has no attribute 'urlretrieve'`
Oh I see, I need the code for python 3, I should've specified.

Comment: So this code doesn't do what I'm trying to do. The url would be to a page like `https://www.google.com/search?q=naruto&tbm=isch`
Then the code has to find the first image from the search results and get the html src as a string. I don't want to download the image or save the image directly, I just want the online url for that specific image so that I can add it into my own img tag and put that src in it.